# How does relativity holds for universal speed limit?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light

According to relativity nothing in the universe can move faster than light through space time.

The light always appear to be at c regardless of the velocity of the observer , same is true for any object moving at c.

So how does it happens?

Does the space relatively contracts and expands when the observer is moving towards and away respectively from the direction of light?

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual contraction or relaxation of space. The person on the ground observes your length in the direction of motion to be contracted by a amount proportional to your speed. At the same time, you feel that you are at rest and the universe is moving at very high speed in the opposite direction so that the length of the universe (space) along your motion seems contracted by the very same amount the observer on the ground has calculated.
It contains the two postulates of special relativity. 1) Laws of physics are symmetric in all inertial frames of reference and 2) the speed of light in vacuum is a universal constant and is independent of the relative motion between the observer and the source. There is no actual contraction of space but one observes it due to the fact that the constancy of speed is independent of observer's motion. It's a measurement effect.

Answer (score -2):

**"The light always appear to be at c regardless of the velocity of the observer , same is true for any object moving at c. So how does it happens?"**

Actually it doesn't. See this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect 
 "Assume the observer and the source are moving away from each other with a relative velocity v (v is negative if the observer and the source are moving towards each other). Considering the problem in the reference frame of the source, suppose one wavefront arrives at the observer. The next wavefront is then at a distance λ=c/fs away from the observer (where λ is the wavelength, fs is the frequency of the wave the source emitted, and c is the speed of light)."

If v is small, relativistic time dilation can be neglected. The observer measures the frequency to be

fo = fs(1 - v/c),

and the speed of the light relative to the observer is, accordingly,

c' = λ.fo = c - v,

in violation of Einstein's relativity.

It is easy to see that the relativistic time dilation introduced in the Wikipedia article does not change the conclusion that the speed of the light relative to the observer is different from the speed of the light relative to the source. Einsteinians will have to admit that the Doppler effect, relativistic or not, refutes Einstein's relativity.

Comment: The wavelength of light undergoes length contraction?!? Are you joking?

Comment: My comment above sounds strange - it was a reply to an Einsteinian who then found it suitable to delete his/her comment. Einsteinians have always been extremely honest.